# Creating C++ Named Pipes for Intranet hosts

Tags: c++, windows, ipc, named-pipes

I've been trying to create a named pipes using microsoft code:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppNamedPipeClient-a88eb958

I also took security token from elsewhere:

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)malloc(
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, 
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    // ACL is set as NULL in order to allow all access to the object.
    SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(sa.lpSecurityDescriptor, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
```

I want to declare the server instead of locally, on my ip, for it to be accsessed by other pcs on the intranet:

```
#define SERVER_NAME         L"10.12.13.122" ("." works)
#define PIPE_NAME           L"SamplePipe"
#define FULL_PIPE_NAME      L"\\\\" SERVER_NAME L"\\pipe\\" PIPE_NAME
```

Has anyone declared this for C++ before? this is refusing to create the named pipe...

Comment: What error code/message do you get? Does the error occur when creating the server-side of the pipe (i.e. in CreateNamedPipe()) or on the client-side (i.e. in CreateFile()) ? Have you tried to pass NULL as your security attributes ?

Comment: The server side, and it is 0x7b

Answer (score 1):

0x7B is ERROR_INVALID__NAME. "The pipe server cannot create a pipe on another computer, so CreateNamedPipe must use a period for the server name, as shown in the following example \\.\pipe\PipeName": see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365783.aspx). Don't forget to double the backslashes for string literals.